# redirect wont work in Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a form on my website.
When this form is filled out, it is then validated by a javascript validation function.

At the bottom of this function I have this piece of code:

```
  window.location="../index.html";
```

This wont work on Chrome, but does work in Firefox.

My Q is, how can I make this simple redirect work on all (most) browsers?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is in a separate js file which is included...

Comment: works fine for me on `4.1.249.1064`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "../index.html";
```

... is the preferred way, although setting `window.location` does work in Chrome.

Comment: Do I need relative or absolute paths? Shouldn't matter right... hmm
BTW: This is in a separate js file which is included... Maybe thats the reason?

Comment: Doesn't matter about the separate .js file: the URL is calculated relative to the page, not the .js file. Relative paths are absolutely fine too.

Answer (score 0):

window.location works for me in Google Chrome as well as in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The ../ is not really a valid URL.

If you want to go to your html root (where your index.html is most likely located), simply use "/index.html"